# Error when sending qbposxml request for purchase orders. TxnID - a filter for this field is already defined

Tags: qbxml

I am getting an error when submitting a request to QuickBooks POS using qbposxml.

The following request is seeking to query specific purchase orders by transactions ID (TxnID).  The spec says I can add 0-n such filters.  But I get the following error. TxnID - a filter for this field is already defined

This works in regular qbxml. Why does it return this error.

Here is a copy of the qbposxml.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <?qbposxml version="3.0"?>
     <QBPOSXML>
       <QBPOSXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
         <PurchaseOrderQueryRq requestID="1030" iterator="Start">
           <MaxReturned>2000</MaxReturned>
           <TxnID>-2225105152006782719</TxnID>
           <TxnID>-2208405401119063807</TxnID>
           <TxnID>-2225038721336573695</TxnID>
           <TxnID>-2208373171575422719</TxnID>
           <TxnID>-2190108440637046527</TxnID>
           <PurchaseOrderStatusDesc>Open</PurchaseOrderStatusDesc>
         </PurchaseOrderQueryRq>
       </QBPOSXMLMsgsRq>
     </QBPOSXML>
```

Answer (score 0):

TxnID can only be listed once in a query.

See the OSR for details. http://developer-static.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html